# Is there a way to access RDD partitions info from Spark Context?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, caching, rdd

I'm new on Apache Spark and I am using version 2.4.3 pre-built for Hadoop 2.7.   I need to collect partition information about RDD cached. I would like to get from `SparkContext sc` the same information that I see in Web Ui into Storage Tab -> RDD detail page and in particular `Block Name`, `Storage Level`, `Size in Memory`, `Size on Disk`, `Executors` for each RDD cached.

I've tried to call `getRDDStorageInfo` from `Spark Context` but it returns `RDDInfo` objects with only the number of partitions and not the partition detail.

```
scala> sc.getRDDStorageInfo
res17: Array[org.apache.spark.storage.RDDInfo] = Array(RDD "small RDD" (0) StorageLevel: StorageLevel(memory, deserialized, 1 replicas); CachedPartitions: 4; TotalPartitions: 4; MemorySize: 232.0 B; DiskSize: 0.0 B)
```

Is there any way to get the partitions detail for each existent partition from Spark Context?